# How to open pdf file in swift directly from URL

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am new in swift and I am unable to open pdf file from url

my code is like this

```
 @IBOutlet var webview: WKWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        webview.navigationDelegate = self

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf")
        self.webview.load(URLRequest(url: url!))

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Start loading")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("End loading")
    }
```

I am using this code I am able to open url link and image but not able to open pdf file

Comment: what happens when you run above code

Comment: @user1374 it shows nothing.

Comment: have you set a delegate if WKWebView WKNavigationDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load a http-Url into a WebView which is prohibited by default in iOS. You can try the same code with an https-Url or change your Transport Security Settings in the Info.plist to allow Arbitrary loads

Another useful idea might be to use SFSafariViewController to show a website or document from another url.

Answer (score 3):

If you use >= iOS 11 you can use Apples `PDFKit`. Here example.

```
import PDFKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(pdfView)

        if let url = URL(string: link_of_pdf), let document = PDFDocument(url: url) {
            pdfView.document = document
        }
    }
}
```

But if you need support for less than iOS 11, you can use `CGPDFDocument`(but you need to work a lot with this), or find third party lib.

Comment: what if URL has changed pdf to web URL

Comment: You can use web URL as well

Answer (score 0):

> try this below code and let me know

```
 @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.initialSetup()
    }

    private func initialSetup () {
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.loadHTMLStringImage()

    }

    private func loadHTMLStringImage() -> Void {
            let htmlString = "<p>Identify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the imagesIdentify the arrow-marked structures in the images</p>"
            webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `WKWebView` because you can use most common approach, and that is using `UIDocumentInteractionController` and `UIAlertController`

Check this part of code that is using popular `Alamofire` with progressview (you can use any library that you like for similar functionality and also `URLSession` of course).

Note if you are using this in your controller, it must implement delegate `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`.

Here is the full source code with download function and progressbar:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

        var progressView: UIProgressView?    

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }               

        func downloadCommentFile(id: Int) {
            let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)  

            //MARK: Progress controller
            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Downloading", message: "Downloading file", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

            //  Show UIAlertController it to your users
            present(alertView, animated: true, completion: {
                //  Add your progressbar after alert is shown (and measured)
                let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
                let rect = CGRect(x: margin, y: 72.0, width: alertView.view.frame.width - margin * 2.0 , height: 10.0)
                self.progressView = UIProgressView(frame: rect)
                self.progressView!.progress = 0
                self.progressView!.tintColor = self.view.tintColor
                alertView.view.addSubview(self.progressView!)
            })

            let url = "http://MyUrl/DownloadFile"
            let headers = ["Header1": "header 1 value"]

            Alamofire.download(url,
                method: .post,
                parameters: ["id": id],
                encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                headers: headers,
                to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    //progress closure                  
                    self.progressView?.setProgress(Float(progress.fractionCompleted), animated: true)
                }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                    //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
                    //result closure
                    alertView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                        let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL!)
                        viewer.delegate = self
                        viewer.presentPreview(animated: true)
                })
            })      
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
            return self
        }

        private func documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController!) -> UIView! {
            return self.view
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> CGRect {
            return self.view.frame
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load your pdf file in WKWebView, you can use the following code:-

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView! {
        didSet {
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadWebView()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        hideLoader()
    }

    private func loadWebView() {
        showLoader()
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf)!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.webView.load(request)
        }
    }

    private func showLoader() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //show your loader
        }
    }

    private func hideLoader() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //hide your loader
        }
    }

}

extension WebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        hideLoader()
        showAlert(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        hideLoader()
    }

}
```